# kedro-airflow creates DAGs that throw errors

Tags: python, kedro

I am using kedro-airflow to create a DAG for airflow but the DAG created throws an error (see below).  The flow is just a test flow - very simple - and it runs without errors with kedro run. Airflow also runs other DAGS without any problem.

```
    /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/kedro-environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/implementations/local.py:33: FutureWarning: The default value of auto_mkdir=True has been deprecated and will be changed to auto_mkdir=False by default in a future release.
  FutureWarning,
2020-06-19 15:29:56,812 - airflow.models.dagbag.DagBag - ERROR - Failed to import: /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/b_dag.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/kedro-environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 236, in process_file
    m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/kedro-environment/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/b_dag.py", line 98, in <module>
    runner.run(pipeline, data_catalog)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/kedro-environment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kedro/runner/runner.py", line 97, in run
    if self._is_async:
AttributeError: 'AirflowRunner' object has no attribute '_is_async'
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Thank you!

- Kedro-Airflow plugin version used : 0.2.2
- Airflow version: 1.10.10
- Kedro version used (pip show kedro or kedro -V): 0.16.2
- Python version used (python -V): 3.7.7
- Operating system and version: macOS version 10.15.5 and Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: I believe this error has been fixed in https://github.com/quantumblacklabs/kedro-airflow/pull/54, but the fix has not been released it yet. Let me do that early next week. In the meantime (in case you can't wait until next week), an immediate workaround is to use Kedro 0.15.9 as `is_async` was introduced in Kedro 0.16.0.

Comment: Thank you @921Kiyo ! I will give it a try with kedro 0.15.9 and will let you know if that fixed the problem. Also, I do have another question regarding that you might be able to help with? what does exactly "Kedro-Airflow does not support datasets that require Spark." means? That Spark Datasets are not supported? Can't I use kedro-airflow if I use them? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it means SparkDataSet are not supported. We have a task to investigate/verify which cases of SparkDataSet and Airflow don't work (so it might work), but we haven't had a chance to test it in codebase, since the development of Kedro-Airlfow has been parked due to higher priorities in Kedro side.

Comment: thanks again. I've just tried to use Kedro 0.15.9 without success - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kedro.framework' .  I guess I will wait for that release and try it again with 0.16 when it's done

Comment: `kedro.framework` was also introduced in 0.16.0. If you have any import path like `kedro.framework.context` or `kedro.framework.cli` in your project, that needs to be `kedro.context`, `kedro.cli` since they don't exist in 0.15.9. Nevertheless, I will let you know when a new release is done :)

Comment: Kedro-Airflow 0.3.0 has been released just now https://pypi.org/project/kedro-airflow/0.3.0/ so I hope the issue has been resolved. Thank you for your feedback :)

Comment: Hi @921Kiyo ! Great! Thank you! will give it a try and will let you know if I come across any problems!